# Diagonalization of a symmetric bilinear form over the integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, bilinear-form

Suppose $H$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with integer entries. We can view $H$ as a symmetric bilinear form $H:\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ defined by $H(v,w)=v^tAw$. It is then well known that $H$ is diagonalizable ([http://www.math.toronto.edu/~jkamnitz/courses/mat247_2014/bilinearforms2.pdf](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Ejkamnitz/courses/mat247_2014/bilinearforms2.pdf), Theorem 1.4, for example), i.e. there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^t HP$ is diagonal.

On the other hand, we can view $H$ as a symmetric bilinear form $\Bbb Z^n\times \Bbb Z^n\to \Bbb Z$. Suppose $\det H=\pm 1$ and that $H$ is negative definite. Then can we find an invertible matrix $P\in GL(n,\Bbb Z)$ such that $P^t HP$ is diagonal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. These matrices define positive definite (by taking $-H$) [unimodular lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_lattice); if $-H$ is diagonalizable then the diagonal entries must all be equal to $1$, so the corresponding lattice must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with the usual Euclidean inner product. The smallest example of a positive definite unimodular lattice not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ occurs in dimension $8$ and is given by the [$E_8$ lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_lattice). It cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ because it is even, meaning that $H(v, v)$ is always even.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a classification result of such diagonalizable bilinear forms?

Comment: @user302934: what kind of classification are you looking for? They correspond to matrices of the form $P^T P$ where $P \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ (taking the positive definite version as above).

Comment: Given a positive definite symmetric matrix, is there a way to determine whether it is diagonalizable over the integers?

Comment: @user302934: this seems potentially difficult. You'll find more references by searching about ways to determine when two lattices or especially two unimodular lattices are isomorphic. I found this MO discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374474/deciding-isometry-of-unimodular-lattices-by-gram-matrices