# Determining an integral positive-definite symmetric matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb Z$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, positive-definite, bilinear-form

According to this question: [Diagonalization of a symmetric bilinear form over the integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539778/diagonalization-of-a-symmetric-bilinear-form-over-the-integers/4539826#4539826), not all definite symmetric matrices with integer entries are diagonalizable over $\Bbb Z$. (Here we are considering diagonalization of a bilinear form, so this means that given a definite symmetric matrix $H \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb Z)$, we cannot always find an invertible matrix $P\in GL(n,\Bbb Z)$ such that $P^t HP$ is diagonal.) I am curious about: if we are given an explicit definite symmetric integral matrix, then is there a way (or algorithm) to determine whether it is diagonalizable over $\Bbb Z$?

Actually I want to determine whether the negative-definite matrix
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 &  \\ 1 & -2 & \\ 1 & & -5 & \\1 & & & -4 & 1 \\ & & & 1 & -2 &  \\1 & & & & & -71 & 1 \\ & & & & & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$
is diagonalizable over $\Bbb Z$. Using elementary row&column operations (corresponding to $E^tAE$ for some integral elementary matrix $E$), I've got $$ A'=\begin{bmatrix} -1   \\  & -1 & \\  & & -3 & 2 & & 2 \\ & & 2 & -2 & 1 & 2 \\ & & & 1 & -2 &  \\ & & 2 & 2 & & -69 & 1 \\ & & & & & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} ,$$
and it seems $A'$ is not diagonalziable because the $5\times 5$ submatrix of $A'$ doesn't seem diagonalizable. Is there a way to prove that $A$ is not diagonalziable?

Comment: if $A$  diagonalizes over the integers, the outcome is minus the identity matirx, quadratic form minus the sum of seven squares. So,  found out how many times your form represents $-1$  with integer vectors. If your form diagonalizes it represents $-1$   exactly $14$ times.  Similar idea for representing $-2, -3,...$

Comment: We have $P^tAP=-I$ where
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&1&4&6&4&70&70\\
0&1&2&3&2&35&35\\
0&0&1&1&1&14&14\\
0&0&1&2&1&20&20\\
0&0&0&1&1&10&10\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1}.
$$
Equivalently, $-A=X^tX$ where
$$
X=P^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&-1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&-1&-1&0&-1&0\\
0&0&1&0&-1&-4&0\\
0&0&-1&1&0&-6&0\\
0&0&1&-1&1&-4&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1}.
$$

Comment: @user1551  wow. How did you get that?   I have software to do this in three and four variables.

Comment: @WillJagy The usual method: elementary row/column operations. Or more precisely: shear matrices. Oh, and I did this manually, but using Octave (the Matlab clone) as my scientific calculator.

Comment: @user1551   modified my rational congruence program  to let me specify one (shear) step at a time, as you suggest.  I should add in something to switch rows/columns and negate one .... $$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 & 1 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix describes a unimodular 7-dimensional lattice. It is known that those are always “trivial“ (the first non-trivial example is the $E_8$ lattice in dimension $8$).
However, in general is a difficult problem to decompose a given lattice. In your case the LLL algorithm works. Using GAP the command `LLLReducedGramMat` yields
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&4&4&-6&70&70\\
.&1&2&2&-3&35&35\\
.&.&1&1&-1&14&14\\
.&.&1&1&-2&20&20\\
.&.&.&1&-1&10&10\\
.&.&.&.&.&1&1\\
.&.&.&.&.&.&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Interestingly, this is close to @user1551's matrix. Also in Magma, there is the command `OrthogonalDecomposition`, which should always give a definite answer.

Comment: gp-Pari  has  LLL as well. I never thought of using it here.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference for the statement that a unimodular lattice of rank $<8$ is always trivial?

Comment: [Conway-Sloane, "Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups"] or just https://oeis.org/A005134